# How to retrieve an array of values from a persistent map?

Tags: nearprotocol

I created a persistent map and set a key/value pair; however when I try to later retrieve an array of values using `.values`, an empty array with 0 items in it is returned.

I double checked to see if the keys I'm searching for are contained, and they are.

Here's my code:
`let members = new PersistentMap<string, Member>('memberss');`

`members.set(summoner , member2)`

`` let numMembers = members.values(`satosh`, `rico`, -1, true); ``

```
    export function getMembers(): Array<Member> { 
      let numMembers = members.values(`satosh`, `null`, -1, true);
      return numMembers
  }
```

I've also tried using a second string key instead of null, but still get an empty array returned.

How do I resolve [this](https://github.com/nearprotocol/near-runtime-ts/blob/8dedca2a19213e5c60db3cef89f51e759a29c36e/assembly/collections/persistentMap.ts#L36)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried to use values and works for me. Here is the example that I used: https://studio.nearprotocol.com/?f=ifvnwzwpa

Snippets:

```js
let messageMap = new PersistentMap<string, PostedMessage>("mm"); 

export function addMessage(text: string): void {
  let message: PostedMessage = {
    sender: context.sender,
    text: text
  };
  messageMap.set(text, message);
}

export function getMessages(): Array<PostedMessage> {
  return messageMap.values("a", "z", -1, true);
}
```